# Flash ECC algorithm on STM32L1xx

Tags: algorithm, embedded, stm32, flash-memory

How does the flash ECC algorithm (Flash Error Correction Code) implemented on STM32L1xx work?

Background:
I want to do multiple incremental writes to a single word in program flash of a STM32L151 MCU without doing a page erase in between. Without ECC, one could set bits incrementally, e.g. first 0x00, then 0x01, then 0x03 (STM32L1 erases bits to 0 rather than to 1), etc. As the STM32L1 has 8 bit ECC per word, this method doesn't work. However, if we knew the ECC algorithm, we could easily find a short sequence of values, that could be written incrementally without violating the ECC.

We could simply try different sequences of values and see which ones work (one such sequence is 0x0000001, 0x00000101, 0x00030101, 0x03030101), but if we don't know the ECC algorithm, we can't check, whether the sequence violates the ECC, in which case error correction wouldn't work if bits would be corrupted.

[Edit] The functionality should be used to implement a simple file system using STM32L1's internal program memory. Chunks of data are tagged with a header, which contains a state. Multiple chunks can reside on a single page. The state can change over time (first 'new', then 'used', then 'deleted', etc.). The number of states is small, but it would make things significantly easier, if we could overwrite a previous state without having to erase the whole page first.

Comment: The ECC is calculated automatically when the data is written.  However unlike most flash memory devices, it is not possible to program STM32 data EEPROM flash (or in fact any STM32 flash) unless the word being written is _entirely_ in the erase state.  You will have to perform a read-modify-write on the entire word if you want to change individual bits.  I suspect this is your real problem rather then ECC not being correct.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! When writing sequences like 0x01, 0x03, one after the other into the same flash mem location w/o an erase in between, everything works as expected (when reading back, we get 0x01 first and then 0x03). But when writing sequences like 0x03, 0x07, this doesn't work (reading back after writing 7 results in 3). This seems to be related to ECC. As the ECC bits themselfs are persisted to flash, they too can only be written in an incremental manner (setting/clearing additional bits). So to my understanding, incremental writing should work for *some* sequences.

Comment: Not according to the the [Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/cc/f9/93/b2/f0/82/42/57/CD00240193.pdf/files/CD00240193.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00240193.pdf).  Depending on the state of FTDW flag the the target word will either be erased automatically, or will fail to be programmed unless it is zero.  Either way the ECC is set automatically as part of the write process, and bit-level incremental programming is not supported.

Comment: This is an XY question; you have problem X, decided erroneously that the solution is Y and are asking about Y, when you should ask about X - or read the reference manual; it is quite clear in this subject.

Comment: The data EEPROM has 7 write modes (reference manual pages 66 to 70) - which are you using?

Comment: Pages 66 to 70 are about data EEPROM, I'm interested in writing to program mem. I'm using the FLASH_FastProgramWord lib function (pg 65). The doc states that the op is "assuming that it [the mem] was previously erased." But empirically we can find out, that some write sequ. (eg. 0x01, then 0x03) work w/o erase in between, while others don't (eg. 0x03, 0x07). STM32L1 seems to behave deterministically in this regard. It seems, that this is related to ECC. But a better question might be "is this a deterministic behaviour, why do some sequences work while others don't and how can we predict it"?

Comment: The reference manual only mentions ECC with respect to the Data EEPROM flash - hence my assumption.  The datasheet however does state that ECC applies to the entire flash  I cannot imagine anyone outside of ST's chip designers could definitively tell you what the algorithm was; an this is still an XY problem.

Comment: Most likely you can only set a bit if the ECC also only sets bits.  I doubt you will find any long sequences where this is true.  You need 7 bits for single-bit error correction and they will look pretty random relative to the data.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would expect (that I can only set a bit if the ECC also only sets bits or doesn't change at all). I was looking for a sequence of ~5 values. For any word that has N bits cleared, there should be ~2^(N-7) other values that only set additional bits and have the exact same ECC value. Based on that, my estimation is, that sequences of 13 values should easily be possible, even with the same ECC. However, as no documentation on the subject seems to exist, I'm not going to rely on multiple writes w/o erase. Nevertheless, I think the answer to my question would still be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for any comments! As there are no answers so far, I'll summarize, what I found out so far (empirically and based on comments to this answer):

- According to the STM32L1 datasheet "The whole non-volatile memory embeds the error correction code (ECC) feature.", but the reference manual doesn't state anything about ECC in program memory.
- The datasheet is in line with what we can find out empirically when subsequentially writing multiple words to the same program mem location without erasing the page in between. In such cases some sequences of values work while others don't.

The following are my personal conclusions, based on empirical findings, limited research and comments from this thread. It's *not* based on official documentation. Don't build any serious work on it (I won't either)!

- It seems, that the ECC is calculated and persisted per 32-bit word. If so, the ECC must have a length of at least 7 bit.
- The ECC of each word is probably written to the same nonvolatile mem as the word itself. Therefore the same limitations apply. I.e. between erases, only additional bits can be set. As stark pointed out, we can only overwrite words in program mem with values that:

  - Only set additional bits but don't clear any bits
  - Have an ECC that also only sets additional bits compared to the previous ECC.
- If we write a value, that only sets additional bits, but the ECC would need to clear bits (and therefore cannot be written correctly), then:

  - If the ECC is wrong by one bit, the error is corrected by the ECC algorithm and the written value can be read correctly. However, ECC wouldn't work anymore if another bit failed, because ECC can only correct single-bit errors.
  - If the ECC is wrong by more than one bit, the ECC algorithm cannot correct the error and the read value will be wrong.
- We cannot (easily) find out empirically, which sequences of values can be written correctly and which can't. If a sequence of values can be written and read back correctly, we wouldn't know, whether this is due to the automatic correction of single-bit errors. This aspect is the whole reason for this question asking for the actual algorithm.
- The ECC algorithm itself seems to be undocumented. Hamming code seems to be a commonly used algorithm for ECC and in [AN4750](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/15/54/c4/5d/90/ed/4f/ce/DM00220769.pdf/files/DM00220769.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00220769.pdf) they write, that Hamming code is actually used for error correction in SRAM. The algorithm may or may not be used for STM32L1's program memory.
- The [STM32L1 reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/66/71/4b/23/94/c3/42/c8/CD00277537.pdf/files/CD00277537.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00277537.pdf) doesn't seem to explicitely forbid multiple writes to program memory without erase, but there is no documentation stating the opposit either. In order not to use undocumented functionality, we will refrain from using such functionality in our products and find workarounds.

Comment: The FLASH memory in the Lxxxx devices has not been considered as EEPROM memory replacement for the user data. It is because those devices often work in the the border power conditions the data has to checked. Most STM32f1 devices have EEPROM memory which has much higher retention rate and this one should be used for the user data.

Answer (score 1):

Interessting question.

First I have to say, that even if you find out the ECC algorithm, you can't rely on it, as it's not documented and it can be changed anytime without notice.

But to find out the algorithm seems to be possible with a reasonable amount of tests.
I would try to build tests which starts with a constant value and then clearing only one bit.
When you read the value and it's the start value, your bit can't change all necessary bits in the ECC.

Like:

```
for <bitIdx>=0 to 31
  earse cell
  write start value, like 0xFFFFFFFF & ~(1<<testBit)
  clear bit <bitIdx> in the cell
  read the cell
next
```

If you find a start value where the erase tests works for all bits, then the start value has probably an ECC of all bits set.
**Edit:** This should be true for any ECC, as every ECC needs always at least a difference of two bits to detect and repair, reliable one defect bit.
As the first bit difference is in the value itself, the second change needs to be in the hidden ECC-bits and the hidden bits will be very limited.

If you repeat this test with different start values, you should be able to gather enough data to prove which error correction is used.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I agree, that, as the algorithm seems to be undocumented, relying on any algorithm we find empirically, wouldn't be a good idea. And I acutally like your algorithm, though I'm not convinced, it's gonna work reliably. Whether _"If you find a start value where the erase tests works for all bits, then the start value has probably an ECC of all bits set."_ is actually true, heavily depends on the actual algorithm.

Comment: @MarkusM I've edited my answer - why I think that my statement probably is true

Comment: To my understanding, the algorithm would show, that all tried values wouldn't set additional bits in the ECC, compared to the start value's ECC. But what if there are bits in the ECC, that aren't set _by any_ of the values tried, neither by the start value, nor by any of the later values? Whether this algorithm would set each bit of the ECC at least once (which to my understanding is the algorithm's preassumption) would depend on the actual ECC algorithm. As you stated correctly, the ECC would __probably__ have all bits set, but we wouldn't know for sure.